# Android custom Progress Dialog - setCancelable()

Tags: java, android, dialog

I had created a custom `Progress Dialogue`. Overriding properties like `setCancelable()` , `setCanceledOnTouchOutside()` doesn't worked for me.

```
public class CustomProgressDialogue extends ProgressDialog {

    private final Context context;

    public CustomProgressDialogue(Context context) {
        super(context);
        this.context = context;
        getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(android.graphics.Color.TRANSPARENT));
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.progress_view);

    }

    // Didn't worked
    @Override
    public void setCancelable(boolean flag) {
        super.setCancelable(false);
    }
    // Didn't worked
    @Override
    public void setCanceledOnTouchOutside(boolean cancel) {
        super.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
    }
}
```

But the same time applying same properties after the instance creation worked.

```
// Worked
progressDialogue = new CustomProgressDialogue(getContext());
        progressDialogue.setCancelable(false);
        progressDialogue.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
```

Could you please somebody can explain this?

Comment: why set `MetricsProgressDialogue` ? instead of `CustomProgressDialogue ` ?

Comment: Sorry that was a copy-paste mistake.Corrected now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead of overriding the cancel-able method create a static method like this and then pass it the required options

here's how ProgressDialog class do this:

```
 public static ProgressDialog show(Context context, CharSequence title,
            CharSequence message, boolean indeterminate,
            boolean cancelable, OnCancelListener cancelListener) {
        ProgressDialog dialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
        dialog.setTitle(title);
        dialog.setMessage(message);
        dialog.setIndeterminate(indeterminate);
        dialog.setCancelable(cancelable);
        dialog.setOnCancelListener(cancelListener);
        dialog.show();
        return dialog;
    }
```

Comment: That's a good one.Now only i check ProgressDialog Source code.Got it.:)

Answer (score 1):

You can try with this way

```
 public class CustomProgressDialogue  extends ProgressDialog 
    {

      public static ProgressDialog(Context context) { // This section create Main role .
        CustomProgressDialogue  dialog = new CustomProgressDialogue (context);
        dialog.setCancelable(false); // Add this 
        return dialog;
      }

      public CustomProgressDialogue (Context context) {
        super(context);
      }

      public CustomProgressDialogue (Context context, int theme) {
        super(context, theme);
      }

      @Override
      protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.progress_view);


      }

      @Override
      public void show() {
        super.show();

      }

      @Override
      public void dismiss() 
      {
        super.dismiss();

      }

    }
```

Comment: So , what was wrong in my solution.Is there any issue related to Context

Comment: @DonChakkappan May be . I am not sure . You can use this way . FYI . `static ProgressDialog` create pivot role here .

Comment: Umar's answer is somewhat more apt.So i will up vote you :)

Answer (score 0):

you cann  add

```
  public static ProgressDialog(Context context) {
        CustomProgressDialogue  dialog = new CustomProgressDialogue (context);
        dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
        return dialog;
      }
```

my method is

```
final AlertDialog alertD = new AlertDialog.Builder(context).create();
    alertD.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
```

is work...!

Answer (score 0):

The issue with your code is that you are overriding the cancelable and OutsideTouchCancel in your CustomDialog class but you are not replacing the original code from ProgressDialog class. So when you call super(context) on your constructor it will initiate your dialog with its build in function for Cancelable and OutsideTouchCancel.

So in your constructor of CustomDialog you need to explicitly call

```
dialog.setCancelable(false);
dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false)
```

You are not required to override those function in your custom class.